# Proof by contrapositive for the statement $P \wedge Q \wedge R \ \Rightarrow S$

Tags: logic, proof-writing

I am asking the question not purely for a logic exercise but I am just trying to prove something by contrapositive and this got me confused.

So when $A$ is a statement where, say, three conditions need to hold e.g. $P \wedge Q \wedge R$ and $B := S$, proving the contrapositive would be showing $\neg S \Rightarrow \neg P \lor \neg Q \lor \neg R$. At first I assumed $S$ does not hold **AND** $A$ and $B$ do hold to show that this contradicts $C$ but this is apparently wrong. Now, if I want to prove the contrapositive is the only way by showing that $\neg S$ leads to a contradiction with one of the statements $A,B$ or $C$? This also looks not quite right because if it were the case then surely then that would mean only one of those statements $A, B$ or $C$ imply $S$.

Comment: Let $P=Q=R=\lnot S$

Comment: This is meant to be a hint but I am not seeing it yet.

Comment: (Then $\lnot S\to S$, which is not true (for instance, when $S$ is false).)

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to show that $\neg S$ implies that it's not the case that *all three* of $P, Q,$ and $R$ are true. This is equivalent to at least one of $P,Q,$ and $R$ being false.

Comment: Yes and is not it the same as showing one of the three possibilities
$\neg S \Rightarrow  \neg P$ or $\neg S \Rightarrow  \neg Q$ or $\neg S \Rightarrow  \neg R$.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prove it,  because it's not true.

Let $P=Q=R=\lnot S$. Then $\lnot S\to S$, which is false when $S$ is false.

Comment: In a specific example:
Let A be a statement "$x$ is a multiple of 2,3 and 5". It's the same as $P \wedge Q \wedge R$ where $P$ is $x$ is a multiple of 2,Q is $x$ is a multiple of $3$ and $R$ is $x$ is a multiple of 5. 
Now if S is a statement $x$ is a multiple of 30 then $A \Rightarrow S$ and the contrapositive is $\neg S \Rightarrow \neg A$. Which translates to $x$ is not a multiple of 30 implies $x$ is not a multiple of either $2, 3 $ or $5$.
The statement $A$ implies $S$ is true and so is the contrapositive. To show it do I need to assume $\neg S$ implies $\neg P$ or $\neg Q$ or $\neg S$

Comment: And is not it actually the same as showing $\neg S$ implies (WLOG) $\neg P$ ? It has to be wrong because then the contrapositive of that is $P$ implies $S$ but I can't get my head around on what's going wrong here.